# Typical distances in double slit experiments

Tags: double-slit-experiment

I haven't been able to find the typical distances between walls in the double slit experiments.
For instance, in [this arxiv preprint](https://arxiv.org/abs/1210.6243), they only give the width and height of the slits (plus a mask they use).
My questions are what are the typical distances between the electron gun, the wall with the 2 slits, and the 'detector' (i.e. the wall where the interference pattern is observed); and how apart are the two slits placed from each other.

Answer (score 0):

On page three of your paper is the sentence

> The double-slit consists of two 50-nm-wide slits with a center-to-center separation of 280 nm (see inset 1 in figure 1)

So in this case the gap between the slits is about four times the width of each slit.  That relative spacing helps the double-slit interference pattern to dominate over the single-slit interference pattern.

That section of the paper says that from the electron source to the double slit is about 45 cm (with a collimator in the middle). It doesn't seem to say the distance from the slits to the visualization phosphor. If you know the wavelength of a 600-eV electron and the slit geometry, you can figure out the *angles* between the constructively-interfering rays pretty easily.  However the paper says that they used an electrostatic quadrupole to magnify the pattern.   I conclude from this reading that the whole apparatus fits comfortably on a standard laboratory optical table: less than a couple meters long all together.

The important feature in a double-slit experiment is the relationship between the slit geometry and the wavelength of the interfering particles, so these characteristic sizes can be adjusted by adjusting your source.  I have a dim memory that the first electron-interference experiment used a 50-ish eV electron beam.  That's a tenth the energy of your 2012 paper, so I would expect the older experiment had 10x larger slits to compensate for the longer electron wavelength.